# How can I import files in Python using sys.path.append?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, relative-path, sys

There are two directories on my desktop, `DIR1` and `DIR2` which contain the following files:

```
DIR1:
file1.py

DIR2:
file2.py  myfile.txt
```

The files contain the following:

#### file1.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append('.')
sys.path.append('../DIR2')

import file2
```

#### file2.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append( '.' )
sys.path.append( '../DIR2' )

MY_FILE = "myfile.txt"

myfile = open(MY_FILE)
```

#### myfile.txt

```
some text
```

Now, there are two scenarios.  The first works, the second gives an error.

#### Scenario 1

I [`cd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) into `DIR2` and run `file2.py` and it runs no problem.

#### Scenario 2

I `cd` into `DIR1` and run `file1.py` and it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<absolute-path>/DIR1/file1.py", line 6, in <module>
    import file2
  File "../DIR2/file2.py", line 9, in <module>
    myfile = open(MY_FILE)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myfile.txt'
```

However, this doesn't make any sense to me, since I have appended the path to `file1.py` using the command `sys.path.append('../DIR2')`.

Why does this happen when `file1.py`, when `file2.py` is in the same directory as `myfile.txt` yet it throws an error?

Comment: Python's `sys.path` only affects how Python looks for modules.  If you want to `open` a file, `sys.path` is not involved.  Your `open` is failing because you're not running the script from the directory that contains `myfile.txt`.

Comment: Okay, thanks @larsks.  But, how do I affect how python opens files?  i.e. how do I allow it to open files from a different directory?

Comment: @Hunle use the complete relative path to that file , or best use absolute path if possible.

Comment: Can't use absolute path.  This is a shared application.  Okay, thank you.

Comment: Still....I'm confused.  `myfile.txt` is in the same directory as the file trying to open it `file2.py`.  And, like I said, if I just run `file2.py` alone it works fine.

Comment: You never showed us how you are running the files.  If you're changing into `DIR2` before running `file2` that would explain the behavior you are seeing.  If you're doing anything else, show us the *exact* steps.

Comment: similar question ----> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder][1]

let me know if it helps.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, since it's about `open`, not `import`. People searching on Google for how to import using `sys.path.append()` will find this post a waste of time - and that's where most of the traffic is probably coming from.

Comment: sorry about that. suggest an edit to address  this issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a path relative to a module by using a module's `__file__` attribute.  For example:

```
myfile = open(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    MY_FILE))
```

This should do what you want regardless of where you start your script.

Comment: I would start by printing out the value of the path (`thepath = os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../<different-directory>/', JSON_FILE)`) and seeing if it looks sane.  I'm suspicious that we're dealing with an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) here, because it's not clear from your question exactly why you're trying to access files like this.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
MY_FILE = "myfile.txt"
myfile = open(MY_FILE)
```

with

```
MY_FILE = os.path.join("DIR2", "myfile.txt")
myfile = open(MY_FILE)
```

That's what the comments your question has are referring to as the relative path solution.  This assumes that you're running it from the directory one up from *myfile.txt*... so it is not ideal.

If you know that *my_file.txt* is always going to be in the same directory as *file2.py* then you can try something like this in *file2*...

```
from os import path

fname =  path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "my_file.txt"))
myfile = open(fname)
```

Comment: Can I suggest that you put a print(\_\_file\_\_ + " " + os.getcwd()) call in each of your files .. I think you may have a broken understanding of how the paths are resolved.