# How to create mongodb connection in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have tried following ways but could not achieve the output.

1) Using Mongodb source config and mongodb script
Error: code 13 : unauthorized

2) USing JSR223 Sampler (lang :python)
Error :javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named pymongo in  at line number 6

Code:

import random 
import datetime
import string
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo")
from pymongo import MongoClient

def connection():
    global db
    connection=MongoClient(HOSTNAME,PORT)
    db=connection[DATABASE]
    db.authenticate(USERNAME,PASSWORD)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to [install the `pymongo` package](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Extending-Jython-with-pypi-modules) like:

   ```
   jython -m pip install pymongo
   ```
2. After this you need to [include `site-packages` folder to your package lookup path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239372/how-to-import-files-in-python-using-sys-path-append) like:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append('\\location\\of\\jython\\site-packages')
   ```
3. Once done you will be able to use the above Python code for setting up the MongoDB Connection

---

Be aware that [recommended language for JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) scripting is [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), if you plan to conduct high load using the JSR223 Sampler(s) I would suggest migrating to Groovy and using [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) like:

```
def mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://your_username:your_password@mongohost/?authSource=userdb&ssl=true");
```

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter)