# Python ModuleNotFoundError when importing custom modules

Tags: python, import, module, package, project-structure

I have the following project structure
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k87Dl.png)

- In utils.py I am importing a parse function form parser.py file like this

  `from logica.parser.parser import parse`
- In builder.py I am importing a function from utils.py that uses the parser function like this

  `from utils.utils import utils`

When trying to run all this stuff I get a ModuleNotFoundError:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logica'`

Do you guys have any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can only `import` modules installed via `pip` or files stored in the same directory of the current file.

---

To solve this problem you can do this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<path-of-the-module>)
```

I would suggest to read also [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239372/how-to-import-files-in-python-using-sys-path-append).

Comment: Please can you give us the first lines of your py files with the import statements.

Comment: utils.py file:  from logica.parser.parser import parse

, builder.py:   from utils.utils import utils